# Google App Script stopped working for no reason

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

Earlier, this script was working as intended; it was supposed to retrieve emails within the 'CCTV' label and delete emails older than 60 days. However, for some reason, it doesn't work. I have tried creating a new project, but nothing seems to work.

```
function cleanUp() {
  var delayDays = 60 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash
  var batchSize = 100 // Process up to 100 threads at once
  var searchSize = 400 // Limit search result to a max of 400 threads. Use this if you encounter the "Exceeded maximum execution time" error
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);
   
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("CCTV");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
      {
        threads[i].moveToTrash();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked properly for me. So, even I can confirm that the code is correct. When you say it doesn't work, do you mean that there are emails in "CCTV" label which are older than 60 days and the code is still not deleting those?

Comment: If yes, try debugging step by step by adding console.log statements at a few places. This way you will eventually get closer to the root cause.

Comment: Hi, the script is working – I mean, it starts the execution. However, for some reason, nothing is getting deleted. Earlier, it was working fine without any issues.

Comment: Did you try logging to debug further?
Add "console.log(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject());" at two places - before the IF and inside the IF. 
This will print the subjects of the emails having the label CCTV, post and pre the maxDate. Based on what gets printed, you can analyze why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
```

to this:

```
if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate().valueOf()<maxDate.valueOf())
```

Comment: Not working, although it does start the execution, but nothing gets deleted

12:18:46 PM Notice Execution started
12:18:47 PM Notice Execution completed